# Generic type implementing more than one trait

Tags: generics, rust

Here is my code :

```
struct Node<T: PartialEq & PartialOrd>
{
    left: Box<Option<Node<T>>>,
    right: Box<Option<Node<T>>>,
    value: Option<T>,
}
```

I want to force the T generic type to implement both the PartialEq and the PartialOrd traits. I can't found the synthax to do this (the & char not being the one I look for). Thanks for helping me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The syntax is `+`:

```
struct Node<T: PartialEq + PartialOrd> {
    left: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    right: Option<Box<Node<T>>>,
    value: Option<T>,
}
```

I would also recommend changing `Box<Option<U>>` to `Option<Box<U>>`. This can be represented more efficiently (`None` doesn’t require an allocation, and is in fact represented as a null pointer).